# How does this syntax work: object.(variable, :symbol1, :symbol2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, jbuilder

I'm noticing on the documentation of `jbuilder`:  https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

```
json.(@message, :created_at, :updated_at)
```

I've tested this myself in some code with `jbuilder` and it appears to be synonymous to this:

```
json.created_at(@message.created_at)
json.updated_at(@message.updated_at)
```

But I have never encountered this syntax before, and have never seen such a thing in any other ruby or rails documentation.  Where is this feature in ruby documented?  What *exactly* is it doing, and what caveats are there to it?

EDIT:

After the first answer, I now suspect the `json` object looks something like this, and implements the `call` method:

```
class FakeJson
  def initialize

  end

  def call(obj, *methods)
    methods.each do |method|
      self.public_send(method, obj.public_send(method))
    end
  end

  def method_missing(*args)
    puts "called method with #{args.inspect}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Proc.html#method-i-call),

> prc.() invokes prc.call() with the parameters given. It’s a syntax sugar to hide “call”.

It works like:

```
->x, y, z{x + y + z}.(1, 2, 3)
# => 6
```

I guess `json` is a proc or some other object on which `call` is defined, and it is `call`-ed with three arguments `@message`, `:created_at`, and `:updated_at`.

Comment: Oh!  I think I get it now.  JBuilder has it's own DSL inside of the block where you create the json output.  I think the `json` object might look something like (my edit above)

Comment: json is the proc, not @message

Comment: It's not *actually* a proc, it just implements the `call` method.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Generally you expect to see a dot '.' before a method name:

```
"Hello".index("e")
```

Where index is the name of the method and "e" is the argument to said method.  It just so happens that I used parenthesis but that is not required:

```
"Hello".index "e"
```

So you'd think that in the case you are referring to, that () is the name of the method which isn't exactly true.  It's just syntactic sugar.

In the case of a Proc object (or a general object that implements #call),  `obj.(args)` is equivalent of `obj.call(args)`  or even (only in the case of a true Proc) `obj[args]`.

Comment: It is indeed syntax sugar, and is convoluted, but notice that `()` in `.()` is in fact **obligatory** (`->x{x}. 1 # => error`), and is not the same as `()` in ordinary method call, which is optional. So in a sense, you can say `()` itself is the method name, but it also works as the `()` for surrounding the arguments just like in the case of the method `[]`.

Comment: Good point, also note <code>-> x, y {x+y}.((4,5)) # => error</code> which basically says if the outer parens are the 'method name' then this particular 'method' doesn't allow the use of inner parens like all other 'methods'...yes I agree, convoluted :).